# Geopandas pickle incompatibility between 2 versions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, geopandas

**Package versions when I dump geo data frame obj by pickle.**

- scikit-image=0.17.2
- scikit-learn=0.22.1
- geopandas==0.7.0
- pandas=1.0.3

Dump geo data frame by pickle

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
pickle_file_path = "geo_data_frame.pkl"  # file is attached
gdf.to_pickle(pickle_file_path)  # gdf is geo data frame obj for example like gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs="epsg:4326")
```

**Package versions when I read pickled file.**

- scikit-image=0.19.2
- scikit-learn=1.0.2
- geopandas==0.10.2
- pandas=1.0.3

Read pickle

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
pickle_file_path = "geo_data_frame.pkl"  # file is attached
gdf = pd.read_pickle(pickle_file_path)
```

Traceback:

```
---> 58                 gdf = pd.read_pickle(pickle_file_path)
     59                 shutil.rmtree(tempdir)
     60                 return pickle.dumps(gdf)

/opt/conda/envs/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py in read_pickle(filepath_or_buffer, compression)
    180                 # We want to silence any warnings about, e.g. moved modules.
    181                 warnings.simplefilter("ignore", Warning)
--> 182                 return pickle.load(f)
    183         except excs_to_catch:
    184             # e.g.

/opt/conda/envs/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas/array.py in __setstate__(self, state)
    422     def __setstate__(self, state):
    423         if compat.USE_PYGEOS:
--> 424             geoms = pygeos.from_wkb(state[0])
    425             self._crs = state[1]
    426             self._sindex = None  # pygeos.STRtree could not be pickled yet

KeyError: 0
```

You can directly download pickle file in above code from https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VTDaapxsy6DosMmrSv9mUtVzNBn_ISeN/view?usp=sharing

[Screenshot in sentry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZHXv.png)

Comment: Please post the code or error as text in your question, not an image.

Comment: Please post the full traceback error.

Comment: Thanks for attentions!. I just elaborated my post as much as I can. I tried to attach pkl file but couldn't find attachment feature here.

Comment: I just added download link for pkl file. :)

Comment: Pickle is not meant for long-term data storage. GeoPandas does offer some backwards compatibility for pickle files but 0.7 - 0.10 is probably a too large of a gap. Try using older geopandas to read the file and save it to some standardised file format.

Comment: generally, it's not a good idea to rely on pickle at all for cross-version compatibility (not just a geopandas issue). pickle relies on the package maintainers either providing a stable pickle protocol (see @martinfleis's comment) or requires that the pickled objects be identical in API/attributes/etc across versions. Using a defined, stable file format such as GeoJSON, ESRI shapefile, GeoParquet, etc is a much better strategy for long-term or cross-version data storage.

Comment: I could solve this issue by exporting gdf to parquet which is compatible for back and forth versions. Thanks for all comments.